# Importar builtins optimiza?

Tags: python, optimización

El archivo `builtins.pyi` se puede importar, entonces tengo una pregunta ¿Mejora la velocidad de ejecución importar las funciones que se usa en vez de no hacerlo?

Con lo que me refiero con esto es si hacer: `from builtins import (Las funciones que se usan en el archivo)` es mejor que dejar que Python importe todos los builtins (Que supongo que es lo que hace automáticamente)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, la misión del módulo `builtins` no es aumentar la velocidad ni mucho menos. El módulo podría pensarse que es completamente innecesario, ya que los "builtins" son realmente identificadores de funciones que forman parte del lenguaje, sin necesidad de incluir módulo alguno. El intérprete no hace un `import` automático de ese módulo al arrancar tampoco. Simplemente, esos identificadores (`print`, `open`, y otros) forman ya parte del intérprete (y están internamente implementados en C).

Por ejemplo, un "builtin" es la función `print`, ya que esa función forma parte del lenguaje y se puede usar directamente sin importar nada, como muestra el siguiente ejemplo mínimo, que es un programa Python completo:

```
print("Hola mundo")
```

### Entonces ¿por qué existe el módulo `builtins`?

Ocurre que los "builtins" no son *palabras reservadas*, como sí lo son por ejemplo `if` o `while`. Si algo es una palabra reservada en un lenguaje significa que tú no puedes definir un identificador con ese nombre. Si lo intentas, tienes un error, como verás si pruebas a ejecutar el siguiente ejemplo:

```
print("Esto no va a funcionar")
while = 2
```

Obtienes un error de sintaxis en la segunda línea y el programa ni siquiera empieza a ejecutarse (pues los errores de sintaxis se encuentran en tiempo de "compilación", antes siquiera de comenzar la ejecución).

No ocurre esto con los builtins, que puedes utilizar como identificadores sin problemas:

```
print("Esto sí va a funcionar")
print = 2
```

La ejecución de esto transcurre sin problemas. Naturalmente a partir de la línea `print = 2` hemos redefinido el símbolo `print` que es ahora el entero 2 en vez de la función que solía ser. Por tanto ya no podremos imprimir nada:

```
print("Esto sí va a funcionar")
print = 2
print("Y qué va a pasar aquí?")
```

---

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Tiene sentido, no podemos llamar a `print` ahora porque ahora es un entero.

**Para esto** existe el módulo `builtins` y es por si alguna parte del código ha redefinido alguno de esos símbolos y por tanto ya no tenemos forma de acceder a su significado original. En `builtins` se tienen todos los builtins con su significado estándar, por tanto una forma de resolver el lío en que nos hemos metido en el ejemplo anterior sería:

```
print("Esto sí va a funcionar")
print = 2

import builtins
builtins.print("Y qué va a pasar aquí?")
```

O incluso podríamos "recuperar" el significado original de `print` haciendo `print = builtins.print`. Pero de hecho el programa incurrirá en un pequeño penalty en cuanto a su rendimiento, ya que antes de que anduviéramos manipulando el significado de `print`, este formaba parte directamente del intérprete, mientras que ahora está en una variable que apunta al significado original. Es decir, se añade un nivel de indirección y por tanto un "opcode" extra que debe ser ejecutado por el intérprete para acceder a ese significado.

Naturalmente la mejor opción es **no utilizar como identificadores los builtins**. Por eso el uso de este módulo es más bien anecdótico.

Comment: El módulo `builtins` tiene un uso único, un tanto _curioso_: durante una sesión interactiva, la variable `_` donde almacena el último resultado no es en sí una variable global. El único modo de acceder a ella _"fuera de línea"_ es a través de `builtins._`. Es importante tenerlo en cuenta con las librerías que modifican el `sys.displayhook` como ipython o rich (Se comenta en la documentación de [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook)).

Answer (score 0):

He hecho una prueba. Y no, no beneficia. Según los resultados de la prueba, hasta perjudica (Pero creo que eso es solo porque no lo he ejecutado suficientes veces)

Código usado:

```
from builtins import print, list, range
import time

start = time.time()
buffer: list = []
print("Hello, World!")
for i in range(10000):
    buffer.append(i)
print(buffer)
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

En un archivo la primera línea está, en el segundo archivo no.

Primer archivo:
`~0.024s`

Segundo archivo:
`~0.024s`

Lo que buscaba yo era si `enlazar dinámicamente` (Importar los `builtins` uno a uno) era mejor que `enlazar estáticamente` (Dejar que Python (O el interpretador
/ compilador de cualquier otro lenguaje) importe las funciones más comúnes por tí)

Pero ya vemos que **no, importar los `builtins` uno a uno no mejora la velocidad**